# how to count conditioned continuous values in a list with linq?

Tags: c#, linq, list, indexing

I've list like this:

```
var query = Enumerable.Range(0, 1440).Select((n, index) =>
{
    if ((index >= 480 && index <= 749) || (index >= 810 && index <= 999) || (index >= 1080 && index <= 1299))
        return 0;
    else if (index >= 750 && index <= 809)
        return 1;
    else
        return 2;
});
```

So, Can I find how much indexes have "0" value continuously and which are their indexes - even if interrupts by "1" (not 2) - ?  For example;

```
query[480]=query[481]=query[482]....query[749] = 0, 
query[750]=query[751]...query[809] = 1, 
query[810]=query[811]....query[999] = 0, 
query[1000]?query[1001]...query[1079] = 2, 
query[1080]=query[1081]....query[1299] = 0, etc..
```

So, the answer is 270 (before 1) + 190 (after 1) = 460
Although between 1080 and 1299 indexes have 0, they should not be considered because previous values are "2".

How can I find their sum and indexes?

Comment: gotta love magic numbers..

Comment: if the the result from your query is 0,1,2,1,0,1,0,2,0,1, in this case how many count of group 0 you expected? 2? as the first 0 and last second 0 group is interrupt by "2", right?

Comment: I consider only 0,1,0 flow. If there is an interrupt by "2", I don't consider that.

Comment: It is not a welcome practice to change your question after you got an answer that you accepted. Just ask a new question referencing this one.

Comment: @rene ok. Thanks. New question is in -> http://goo.gl/89YPor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ version as requested:

```
int groupCount = 0;
var result = query
    .Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i })
    .SkipWhile(x => x.Value != 0)                   // Skip until first 0 is reached
    .TakeWhile(x => x.Value == 0 || x.Value == 1)   // Take a continuous series of 0 and 1
    .Where(x => x.Value == 0)                       // Filter out the 1s
    .GroupBy(x =>
        // Treat as a new group if it's:
        // 1) the 1st element, or
        // 2) doesn't equal to previous number
        x.Index == 0 || x.Value != query.ElementAt(x.Index - 1)
            ? ++groupCount
            : groupCount)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Count = x.Count(),
        Start = x.First().Index,
        End = x.Last().Index
    });
```

Result:

```
{ Count = 270, Start = 480, End = 749 }
{ Count = 190, Start = 810, End = 999 }
```

Comment: How can I see this results? Should I convert to list? How?

Comment: @team16sah It's the output from `WriteLine`...The `result` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, you can just loop through it

Comment: How can I get "Count" into my variable c? So, int c = ?
Thanks.

Comment: Dear Fung, there is another problem now. For example my query list like as query{2,2,2, 0,0,0, 3,3, 0,0,0,0, 4,4,4,4, 0,0,0, 2,2, 0,0,0}

Comment: Dear Fung, there is another problem now. For example my query list like as query{2,2,2, 0,0,0, 3,3, 0,0,0,0, 4,4,4,4, 0,0,0, 2,2, 0,0,0}. So result is; {Count = 3, Start = 3, End = 5} {Count = 4, Start = 8, End = 11}. In here, some of values are not considered. They are Last 8 values. (My .TakeWhile line is : .TakeWhile(x => x.Value == 0 || x.Value == 1 || x.Value == 2 || x.Value == 3)). What do you think?

Comment: @team16sah Don't quite get your problem...What's the new expected result? How many groups of zeroes should be found?

Comment: The last 8 values of query list -> 0,0,0, 2,2, 0,0,0. But these must be new beginning

Comment: @team16sah I assume now you'll take continuous values until interrupt by 4. According to original criteria, the last 8 values shouldn't be included because the previous value is 4.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, I want to take the other series by new beginning.. It may take into another list or array. How can I do?