# how to count conditioned continuous values in a list with linq? (Revized)

Tags: c#, linq, list, indexing

I've asked a question some time ago -> [how to count conditioned continuous values in a list with linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345799/how-to-count-conditioned-continuous-values-in-a-list-with-linq)

This question answered by [@Fung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/570036/fung). However, I changed some rules of the question. The new conditions:

```
var query = Enumerable.Range(0, 1440).Select((n, index) =>
    {
        if ((index >= 480 && index <= 749) || (index >= 810 && index <= 999) || (index >= 1080 && index <= 1099) || (index>=1200 && index <= 1299))
            return 0;
        else if ((index >= 750 && index <= 809) || (index >= 1100 && index <= 1199))
            return 1;
        else
            return 2;
    });
```

So, Can I find how much indexes have "0" value continuously and which are their indexes - even if interrupts by "1" (not 2) - ?  For example;

```
query[480]=query[481]=query[482]....query[749] = 0, 
query[750]=query[751]...query[809] = 1, 
query[810]=query[811]....query[999] = 0, 
query[1000]?query[1001]...query[1079] = 2, 
query[1080]=query[1081]....query[1099] = 0, 
query[1100]=query[1101]....query[1199] = 1,
query[1200]=query[1201]....query[1299] = 0, etc..
```

So, the answer is 270 (before 1) + 190 (after 1) = 460
Although between 1080 and 1099 indexes have 0, they should not be considered because previous values are "2".

**In addition, values that from 1080 to 1099 and from 1200 to 1299, should be considered, because they have also new 0 - 1 - 0 serie. And, this serie should be taken another list. Is there a way to accomplish this?**

I've these results now:
[image]

But, because of it divided by "2", I want them in another lists : [image]

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ListStuff
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int End { get; set; }
    public int LType { get; set; }
    public int Group { get; set; }
}


var query = Enumerable.Range(0, 1440).Select((n, index) =>
            {
                if ((index >= 480 && index <= 749) || (index >= 810 && index <= 999) || (index >= 1080 && index <= 1099) || (index >= 1200 && index <= 1299))
                    return 0;
                else if ((index >= 750 && index <= 809) || (index >= 1100 && index <= 1199))
                    return 1;
                else
                    return 2;
            });


        int typeCount = 0;
        int groupCount = 0;
        var result = query
               .Select((x, i) => new
               {
                   Value = x,
                   Index = i,
                   Group = (((i == 0 || (query.ElementAt(i - 1) == 2)) && x != 2) ? ++groupCount : groupCount)
               })
               .GroupBy(x =>
                   x.Index == 0 || x.Value != query.ElementAt(x.Index - 1)
                       ? ++typeCount
                       : typeCount)
               .Select(x => new ListStuff()
               {
                   Count = x.Count(),
                   Start = x.First().Index,
                   End = x.Last().Index,
                   LType = x.First().Value,
                   Group = x.First().Group
               })
               .Where(x => x.LType == 0 || x.LType == 1)
               .GroupBy(x => x.Group)
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not.